# Yocto/Bitbake - Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I'm learning Yocto and I've a problem when creating a custom service.

Here is my recipe structure:

[image]

And the .bb file:

```
SUMMARY = "Analyzer service"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

PR = "r0"

inherit cmake pkgconfig systemd

FILESPATH =+ "${THISDIR}:"

SRC_URI = "\
    file://${PN}"

S = "${WORKDIR}/${PN}"

DEPENDS = "glib-2.0 dlt-daemon"

FILES_${PN} += "${systemd_system_unitdir}/*"
SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "AnalyzerService.service"
```

I've tried to search many similar questions and modify the FILES_${PN}  but it still doesn't work.

```
ERROR: analyzer-service-1.0.0-r0 do_package: QA Issue: analyzer-service: 
Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package:
  /lib
  /lib/systemd
  /lib/systemd/system
  /lib/systemd/system/AnalyzerService.service
Please set FILES such that these items are packaged. Alternatively if 
they are unneeded, avoid installing them or delete them within 
do_install.
analyzer-service: 4 installed and not shipped files. [installed-vs- 
shipped]
ERROR: analyzer-service-1.0.0-r0 do_package: Fatal QA errors were found, 
failing task.
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?
I will be grateful for any help you can provide ^^

Answer (score 2):

Which version is this with? The override syntax changed in more recent versions so it would be FILES:${PN} instead of FILES_${PN} and SYSTEMD_SERVICE:${PN}

Comment: You save my day, I'm using Kirkstone with the new syntax. ^^